# Which all Jmeter listeners should I use to identify all the bottlenecks in my application?

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, jmeter-plugins

**I have some confusions like-**

**1. Which all listener should be used to completely analyze our Application ?**

**2. How to identify the bottlenecks ? (This is the major question)**

**3. How should I create the report ?**

Answer (score 0):

We can use any type of listeners for report creation based on the needs,ie for statistical reports we can use graph results,to find errors test result tree/table is fine,etc

Report should be created for every task,using listeners better always go for script execution in command line mode,create .jtl file to view log information and also to avoid the wastage of resources.

Comment: Ok, can you me an example ? Like, which listers you normally use ? and  with what  goal in mind?

Answer (score 0):

There are many listeners available in JMeter of any can be used. What kind of a sampler/test plan are you planning to test?

Its better to run your test plan in cmd line and generate the reports according to the need. You can generate reports from the .jtl file from cmd line using JMeter plugins.